# Is there a way to rotate the baseline grid in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, grids, rotate

In InDesign, it's possible to rotate a spread to facilitate laying out pages that are meant to be viewed sideways. On a rotated spread, the baseline grid rotates along with the spread—and that's not what I want. I want my line spacing and general typography to be consistent across the entire document, so I want to use this baseline grid on these rotated spreads as well. But then rotated along with my spread.

Is there a way in InDesign to rotate the baseline grid along with the spread display?

Comment: I could be wrong (as always) but I *think* baseline rotation is only possibly the Multi-language version of IND to work with the top-bottom, left-right reading of some languages. I've never used this myself.. merely what I've always understood about the baseline grid.

Comment: @Scott There is a multi-lang version of ID? Makes sense, of course, for TtB, RtL languages like Japanese. You live, you learn :)

Comment: you mean.. You live, you kern.™ `:)`